# Python type hints on mapping to mutable Set

Tags: python, typing

I have written a mapping to a mutable Set in Python. I've used it as a datastructure dealing with file hashes and map the hashes to duplicate files.

I want to apply type hints and have read a lot about Generics and that stuff. Finally, I am not able to solve it well and I ask help from the community:

How does one type annotate the code below correctly?

I know, I could inherit from collections.abc thereby taking advantage of some type hints. However, in the mixin of Mapping and MutableSet I would end up in ducktyped methods such as `__iter__` that are difficut to trace (at least for me). Therefore I chose to write all necessary methods by hand.

I want to supply all possible types, so kind of

```
K = typing.TypeVar('K', bound = typing.Hashable)
```

should be involved. This is necessary for keys in a dict and members of a set.
The code below just deals with Integers.

Thank you very much for your comments!

```
class MtoS(): 
    def __init__(self, x = None):
        self._hashlu= {}
        if isinstance(x, list):
            for t in x:
                self.add(t)
        elif x:
            self.add(x)
    
    def __ior__(self, other):
        for i in other:
            self.add(i)
        return self
    
    def __len__(self):
        return sum([len(x) for x in self._hashlu.values()])

    def add(self, item):
        if item[0] not in self._hashlu:
            self._hashlu[item[0]] = set()
        self._hashlu[item[0]].add(item[1])
    
    def __iter__(self):
        for hash in self._hashlu.keys():
            for file in sorted(self._hashlu[hash]):
                yield hash, file

    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self._hashlu))

    def __repr__(self):
        if not self:
            return '%s()' % (self.__class__.__name__,)
        return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, list(self))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._hashlu[key]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = MtoS([(1,2),(3,4)])
    o = MtoS([(3,4),(3,5),(4,5),(4,6)])
    print(m)        # {1: {2}, 3: {4}}
    print(m[1])     # {2}
    m |= o
    print(m)        # {1: {2}, 3: {4, 5}, 4: {5, 6}}
    print(len(m))   # 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a data structure that can hold many types of items should use `typing.Generic` to let its users specify exactly which types it contains. If there are limits on the types that are valid (such as requiring them to be hashable), you can use bound types and `typing.Protocol`s to specify the requirements.

So I'd annotate your code like this:

```
import typing

K = typing.TypeVar('K', bound=typing.Hashable)         # typevar for keys
V = typing.TypeVar('V', bound="HashableAndSortable")   # typevar for values
class HashableAndSortable(typing.Protocol, typing.Hashable):
    def __lt__(self: V, other:V) -> bool: ...
KV = tuple[K, V]                                       # alias for (key, value)

class MtoS(typing.Generic[K, V]): 
    _hashlu: dict[K, set[V]]
    def __init__(self, x:typing.Optional[KV]|list[KV]=None) -> None: ...
    def __ior__(self, other: "MtoS[K, V]") -> "MtoS[K, V]": ...
    def __len__(self) -> int: ...
    def add(self, item: KV) -> None: ...
    def __iter__(self) -> typing.Iterator[KV]: ...
    def __str__(self) -> str: ...
    def __repr__(self) -> str: ...
    def __getitem__(self, key: K) -> set[V]: ...
```

The hints for `__ior__` are pretty ugly because we need to use strings for forward references. A nicer approach will be possible in Python 3.11, which implements [PEP 673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/), allowing `typing.Self` to be used to annotate a type that's the same as the type of the `self` argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. I have implemented your suggestion in my environment: vscode and python 3.9.7 (on ubuntu). The | syntax for the init type annotation does require python 3.10 and I've used therefore: def __init__(self, x: typing.Union[None, tuple[K,V], list[tuple[K,V]]] = None) -> None: the [K,V] needs to be added to avoid mypy complains, probably also a 3.10 thing. mypy does not complain, everything good. pylance has still some issues.

Comment: If you're having trouble with the `KV` alias for `tuple[K, V]`, you could try using `typing.Tuple[K, V]` instead (you may want similar tweaks for the `dict` and `set` type hints). If you're using `from __future__ import annotations`, the type annotations themselves don't need to be valid Python, they're saved as strings. But that behavior may not be the *actual* future. There was a big debate about making it the default behavior as planned for Python 3.11 and the decision was to wait for now and put off a final decision until Python 3.12 (so more consideration can be given to alternatives).

Comment: Thank you very much Blckknght! Typing seems to be really a hot topic in latest Python development. It's difficult to track what syntax is contained in what python version.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, thanks to Blckknght, I've come up with this specialized solution:

```
import typing as tp
import pathlib as pl

K = tp.TypeVar('K', bound = tp.Hashable)
V = tp.TypeVar('V', bound = pl.PurePath)

class MtoS(tp.Generic[K,V]): 
    _hashlu: dict[K, set[V]]

    def __init__(self, x: tp.Union[None, tuple[K,V], list[tuple[K,V]]] = None) -> None:
        self._hashlu= {}
        if isinstance(x, list):
            for t in x:
                self.add(t)
        elif x:
            self.add(x)
    
    def __ior__(self, other: "MtoS[K,V]") -> "MtoS[K,V]":
        for i in other:
            self.add(i)
        return self
    
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return sum([len(x) for x in self._hashlu.values()])

    def add(self, item: tuple[K,V]) -> None:
        if item[0] not in self._hashlu:
            self._hashlu[item[0]] = set()
        self._hashlu[item[0]].add(item[1])
    
    def __iter__(self) -> tp.Iterator[tuple[K,V]]:
        for hash in self._hashlu.keys():
            for file in sorted(self._hashlu[hash]):
                yield hash, file

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return(str(self._hashlu))

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        if not self:
            return '%s()' % (self.__class__.__name__,)
        return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, list(self))

    def __getitem__(self, key: K) -> set[V]:
        return self._hashlu[key]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = MtoS([(1,pl.Path.home() / "dummy2"),(3,pl.Path.home() / "dummy4")])
    o = MtoS([
        (3,pl.Path.home() / "dummy4"),
        (3,pl.Path.home() / "dummy5"),
        (4,pl.Path.home() / "dummy5"),
        (4,pl.Path.home() / "dummy6")])
    print(m)
    print(m[1])
    m |= o
    print(m)
    print(len(m))
```